# Arithmetic progressions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, additive-combinatorics

What are the largest known lower bounds for $B_k$, the maximal sum of the reciprocals of the members of subsets of the positive integers which contain no arithmetic progressions of length $k$?
for $k=3,4,5,6...$

$B_k\leq$ sup({ $\sum_{n\in S}1/n$ |$S\subset N$|S contains no arithmetic progressions of length k})

And is the bound proved to be finite for any k?
Can there exist a subset for which the maximal bound (finite or infinite), is actually attainable?

Ok, I am interested in any known bounds on $B_k$

Comment: I presume you want an infinite subset? Otherwise the set $\{n\}$ shows that the bound is $0$, and never attained.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: I am asking do you _require_ them to be infinite? (or at least of size $k$?).

Comment: Then what is the problem with $\{n\}$ for arbitrary positive integer $n$?. It has no arithmetic progression of length $\gt 3$, and has reciprocal sum $\frac{1}{n}$, thus giving the "maximal" lower bound to be $0$, which is never attained (or vacuously, attained for the empty set).

Comment: @Aryabhata i attempted a clarification in the question

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Thanks for clarifying :-). Perhaps you need to use supremum instead of max?

Comment: I found something. Still interested in better bounds, also for special cases. http://www.jstor.org/pss/2006472

Comment: Please edit the question to add that reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gerver, Joseph L., 
The sum of the reciprocals of a set of integers with no arithmetic progression of k terms, 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 62 (1977), no. 2, 211–214, MR0439796 (55 #12678) proves for every $\epsilon\gt0$, there exist, for all but a finite number of integers $k\ge3$, $k$-free sets $S_k$ for which $\sum_{n\in S_k}1/n\gt(1−\epsilon)k\log k$. (A $k$-free set is one with no $k$-term arithmetic progression.)

Wróblewski, J., 
A nonaveraging set of integers with a large sum of reciprocals, 
Math. Comp. 43 (1984), no. 167, 261–262,  MR0744935 (85k:11006) constructs a set with no three elements in arithmetic progression such that the sum of the reciprocals of the elements is greater than 3.00849.

Pal, Goutam, 
Sequences of positive integers containing no $p$ terms in arithmetic progression generated by the greedy algorithm, 
J. Ramanujan Math. Soc. 24 (2009), no. 3, 249–263, MR2568055 (2011b:11020) might also be of interest.